# JuliaConnectoR: Translate data frames from R to Julia

Tags: r, juliaconnector

Assume we have a dataframe in R, like this one, but much bigger:

```
planets = data.frame(
    name = c("mercury", "venus", "earth", "mars"),
    distance = c(57.91, 108.21, 146.60, 227.94),    # in million km
    period = c(87.97, 224.70, 365.26, 779.94),      # in earth days
    has.moons = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
planets
##      name distance period has.moons
## 1 mercury    57.91  87.97     FALSE
## 2   venus   108.21 224.70     FALSE
## 3   earth   146.60 365.26      TRUE
## 4    mars   227.94 779.94      TRUE
```

With the help of **JuliaConnectoR** I would like to transfer this dataframe to Julia and apply functions from the 'DataFrames' Julia module to it, e.g., the `describe` function. But somehow I seem to not understand the mechanism (or philosophy) behind it.

```
library(JuliaConnectoR)
DataFrames <- juliaImport("DataFrames")
## Starting Julia ...
```

The following three calls

```
DataFrames$describe(planets)
juliaLet("DataFrames.describe(df)", df = planets)
juliaCall("DataFrames.describe", planets)
```

all generate the following error message

```
## Error: Evaluation in Julia failed.
## Original Julia error message:
## MethodError: no method matching describe(::Main.RConnector.RDataFrame)
```

And generating a proxy object with `juliaPut` does not improve the situation, that is similar error messages will pop up.

```
planets_jl <- juliaPut(planets)
planets_jl
## <Julia object of type Main.RConnector.RDataFrame>
## Main.RConnector.RDataFrame with 4 rows, 4 columns, and an unknown schema.
```

At the moment I solve this problem by in R storing the data frame into a 'feather' file and loading it in Julia, such that 'planets' is a pure Julia object in a Julia environment.

Comment: `describe` seems to be provided by the julia DataAPI package. Is this package available to your julia installation? https://juliapackages.com/p/dataapi

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked all this with Julia. `describe` is only an example. It has something to do with the translation of data frames between R and Julia.

Comment: Just a thought regarding the translation of R types to Julia (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JuliaConnectoR/JuliaConnectoR.pdf, page 3): would `DataFrames$describe(as.list(planets))` work?

Comment: I'm not an expert in `JuliaConnectoR`, but this seems to work: `DataFrames$DataFrame(planets)`

Comment: unsure why you would use this though, when this adds the overhead of two translation layers into every call, especially when you have the feather workaround

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Julia `DataFrame`, which can then be used with `desribe`.

```
planets = data.frame(
    name = c("mercury", "venus", "earth", "mars"),
    distance = c(57.91, 108.21, 146.60, 227.94),    # in million km
    period = c(87.97, 224.70, 365.26, 779.94),      # in earth days
    has.moons = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

library(JuliaConnectoR)
DataFrames <- juliaImport("DataFrames")

DF <- DataFrames$DataFrame(planets)
DataFrames$describe(DF)
#<Julia object of type DataFrames.DataFrame>
#4×7 DataFrame
# Row │ variable   mean     min    median   max     nmissing  eltype
#     │ Symbol     Union…   Any    Union…   Any     Int64     DataType
#─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ name                earth           venus          0  String
#   2 │ distance   135.165  57.91  127.405  227.94         0  Float64
#   3 │ period     364.467  87.97  294.98   779.94         0  Float64
#   4 │ has.moons  0.5      false  0.5      true           0  Bool

DataFrames$select(DF, juliaExpr("(1)"))
#<Julia object of type DataFrames.DataFrame>
#4×1 DataFrame
# Row │ name
#     │ String
#─────┼─────────
#   1 │ mercury
#   2 │ venus
#   3 │ earth
#   4 │ mars

juliaCall("first", DF)
#<Julia object of type DataFrames.DataFrameRow{DataFrames.DataFrame, DataFrames.Index}>
#DataFrameRow
# Row │ name     distance  period   has.moons
#     │ String   Float64   Float64  Bool
#─────┼───────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ mercury     57.91    87.97      false
```

Comment: This is the solution Mark pointed out in the comments above. But it is not really a solution to my problem, as it does not allow me to apply common dataframe commands, e.g., `juliaCall("DF[:, 1]")` will generate an "UndefVarError: `DF` not defined", or even `DataFrames$first(DF)` will say " attempt to apply non-function".

Comment: This is done in a different way. See update for those two additional commands.